# JS : 3 scrollbar synchronized

Tags: javascript, image, scroll

I need help please. 
And thank you !

VERTICAL SCROLL

When ".right" scroll down = ".center" scroll top, ".left" scroll down / & reverse 
When ".left" scroll down = ".center" scroll top, ".right" scroll down / & reverse 
When ".center" scroll down = ".right" scroll down, ".left" scroll down / & reverse

Left & Center are ok but... not Right

**HTML :**

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="contain-img">

        <div class="left">
<img src="img1">
<img src="img2">
<img src="img3">
            </div>

        <div class="center">
<img src="img1">
<img src="img2">
<img src="img3">
            </div>

        <div class="right">
<img src="img1">
<img src="img2">
<img src="img3">
            </div>
</div>
<script src="scroll.js"><script>
</body>
```

**CSS :**

```
.contain-img{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.left, .center, .right{
    height: 300px; 
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.left, .right{
    flex-direction: column;
}
.center{
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.left img, .center img, .right img{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

**JS :**

````
var timeout;

$('.left, .center, .right').on("scroll", function callback() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    var source = $(this),
        target = $(source.is(".left") ? '.center' : '.left');  
    target.off("scroll").scrollTop(-source.scrollTop());

    var source = $(this),
        target = $(source.is(".left") ? '.right' : '.left');  
    target.off("scroll").scrollTop(source.scrollTop());

    var source = $(this),
        target = $(source.is(".center") ? '.right' : '.center');  
    target.off("scroll").scrollTop(-source.scrollTop());

    var source = $(this),
        target = $(source.is(".center") ? '.left' : '.center');  
    target.off("scroll").scrollTop(-source.scrollTop());
    

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        target.on("scroll", callback);
    }, 100);
});```
````

Comment: You have a pair for `.left` and a pair for `.center` but no pair for `.right`.

Comment: Hello, I tried it.
If I make it .left doesn't work.